# How To Use modelBuilder in Foreach And Condition apply on all databse tables

Tags: asp.net-core

In ApplicationDbContext Create Method OnModelCreating();
In This Method   Create variable Like This
After That Create ForEach
My Question Is That How Can I Use entityType Like A Model Name And Apply
HasQueryFilter()

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

***var entitiesList = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes();***

foreach (var entityType in entitiesList)
{
 modelBuilder.Entity.<entityType>()
                    .HasQueryFilter(x=> x.IsDeleted == false);
}

}

            ***
```

> foreach (var entityType in entitiesList)
> {
>
> ```
>  modelBuilder.Entity.<entityType>()
>                     .HasQueryFilter(x=> x.IsDeleted == false)
> }
> ```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{

```
            modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).Property<bool>("IsDeleted");
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "e");
            var body = Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Call(typeof(EF), nameof(EF.Property), new[] { typeof(bool) }, parameter, Expression.Constant("IsDeleted")),
            Expression.Constant(false));
            modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).HasQueryFilter(Expression.Lambda(body, parameter));

        }
```